# Posting comment via Instagram Graph api in Python error

Tags: python-3.x, instagram-graph-api

Am using the following python code to try and post comments to an Instagram media post. Am getting error:

```
    post_id ='nnnnnnnnnnnnn'
    params = dict() 
    params['message'] = 'This is a comment from code'
    params['access_token'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/'+post_id+'/comments?'   
    resp = requests.post(url,params)
```

Here is the error am getting where 'nnnnnnnn' is the post_id passed in:

> '{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID
> '**nnnnnnnnnn**' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
> permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
> API documentation at
> https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"ADoNTClMQwRIi8LEXpkfMr2"}}'

Comment: use a valid post_id

Comment: I am getting [id] from the following. Is that not the correct [id]? https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/{ig-user-id}/recently_searched_hashtags?fields={fields}